# Multiple file Upload From multiple folders

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I would like to implement multiple file upload in a asp.net mvc project with the ability to select multiple files from different folders.Since it is not posssible in some browsers, i thought of creating multiple file upload controls dynamically.On clicking a button one more file upload control will be added that can select multiple files from a single folder.How are the files of each file upload control accessed in the controller and how  canjquery events be binded to the multiple file upload controls and their files?

Comment: Have a look at the code in [mvc-filehelper](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-filehelper)

Comment: im not using razor.im using html controls in my project

Comment: It makes no difference! (but why in the world would you not be using razor (no strong typed model binding, no client side validation etc)